# Time Series Insights Preview - Order By DESC

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

Started using TSI Preview recently and we are trying to get the latest events by using the TSQ GetEvents API, but I can't find any information on how to order the events. Went through the all the documentation but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSI Preview currently does not support customer sorting options for returned events.